# Communication between RESTful API's on same server with NodeJS

Tags: node.js, server, ipc

I am building two sets of services on a website (all written in NodeJS on the server), both are using a RESTful approach. For the sake of modularity I decided to make both services separate entities. The first service deals with the products of the site and the second specifically deals with user related functions. So the first might have functions like getProducts, deleteProduct etc... The second would have functions like isLoggedIn, register, hasAccessTo etc... The product module will make several calls to the user module to make sure that the person making the calls has the privilege to do so.

Now the reason I separated them like this, was because in the near future I foresee a separate product range opening up, but will need to use the same user system as the first (even sharing the same database). The user system will use a database that spans the entire site and all subsequent products

My question is about communication between these projects and the users project. What is the most effective way of keeping the users module separate without suffering any significant speed hits. If the product API made a call to the user API on the same server (localhost), is there a signifcant cost to this, versus building the user API into each of the subsequent projects? Is there a better way to do this through interprocess communication maybe? Is simply having the users API run as its own service an effective solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have two nodes on same server (machine) then you have not bad performance in terms of network latency because both are on localhost. 
Then, nodes will be communicating using a rest api, so on the underground, you will use node js sockets. You could use unix sockets instead of http sockets because are faster BUT are worst to debug, so I recommend you don't to that (but it's ok know alternatives).

And finally, your system looks like an "actor design pattern". At first glance this design patter is a little difficult to understand but you could have a look at this if you want more info about actor model pattern:

- Actor model for NodeJS https://github.com/benlau/nactor
- Actor model explanation http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actor_model

Comment: Thanks Jose, do you have any recommendations on the socket communication? Would socket.io be an effective library for the socket communication?

Comment: You could use socket.io between two nodes but at first glance could be a little tricky. My first choice is package npm "request" (https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) or use native xhr. Anyway, you can test on your local machine the implementation with socket.io and request using "apache benchmark [ab]" to have an idea wich one offers more speed to response the requests.